# iOS app transfer - is it using iCloud entitlement and modifying production app Identifier?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am looking at transferring my iOS app (coded by another developer), but I want to make sure it's not using iCloud entitlements. The iCloud capability is not added to the app and there's no mention of it in the source code.

As per Apple docs having an iCloud entitlement means an app can't be transferred.

When I goto my Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles tab in Apple Developer, I noticed my app identifier has iCloud ticked (but no containers assigned).

My questions are:

1. Can this prevent an app transfer? When I went to the initiate app transfer in App Store Connect everything was ticked green. In comparison for another app that did have iCloud capabilities when I went to initiate app transfer it gave me a warning immediately saying the app uses iCloud.
2. What happens if I untick this iCloud option in the app identifier. My app is in production with users, could this have any impact on users or future builds?

[image: iCloud in Identifier]